# help('modules') crashing? Not sure how to fix

Tags: python

I was trying to install a module for opencv and added an opencv.pth file to the folder beyond my sites.py file.  I have since deleted it and no change.

When I try to run help('modules'), I get the following error:

> Please wait a moment while I gather a
>   list of all available modules...
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/twisted/words/im/**init**.py:8:
>   UserWarning: twisted.im will be
>   undergoing a rewrite at some point in
>   the future.
>   warnings.warn("twisted.im will be
>   undergoing a rewrite at some point in
>   the future.")
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pkgutil.py:110:
>   DeprecationWarning: The wxPython
>   compatibility package is no longer
>   automatically generated or actively
>   maintained.  Please switch to the wx
>   package as soon as possible.
>
> **import**(name) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File
>
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.py",
>   line 348, in **call**
>       return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)   File
>
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py",
>   line 1644, in **call**
>       self.help(request)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py",
>   line 1681, in help
>       elif request == 'modules': self.listmodules()   File
>
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py",
>   line 1802, in listmodules
>       ModuleScanner().run(callback)   File
>
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py",
>   line 1853, in run
>       for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages():   File
>
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pkgutil.py",
>   line 110, in walk_packages
>       **import**(name)   File "/BinaryCache/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-11~262/Root/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/wxaddons/**init**.py",
>   line 180, in import_hook   File
>
> "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/**init**.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       from ctypes_opencv.cv import *   File
>
> "/BinaryCache/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-11~262/Root/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/wxaddons/**init**.py",
>   line 180, in import_hook   File
>
> "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/cv.py",
>   line 2567, in  ('desc', CvMat_r, 1), # CvMat* desc   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/cxcore.py",
>   line 114, in cfunc
>
> ```
> return CFUNCTYPE(result, *atypes)((name, dll), tuple(aflags)) AttributeError: dlsym(0x2674d10, cvCreateFeatureTree): symbol not found
> ```

What gives?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `help('modules')` imports all modules, which can result in a lot of unsentineled code being executed. There's nothing you can do short of reporting bugs in every single package that causes this (opencv in this case) and wait for them to fix it.

Comment: Holy crap...  I didn't even realize that command existed.  Although it's so slow on my system as to be practically useless.  Is that a holdover from an older version of Python?

Comment: interesting, but opencv still doesn't import, so i don't think it's actually executing correctly.

Comment: Now that I think about it, one *could* always supply a patch for the issue as well (assuming we're talking about open source software).  I'm not saying the OP *has* to do this.  I'm just saying it's an option.  :-)

Comment: @Jason: This requires changes to the interface of the module, which means that client software will also need changing.