# Python 2.5 interpreter is throwing a PyNoAppError when I run >>>> help('modules')

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.5

My Python interpreter is giving me an ugly error when I try to pull up a list of all the accessible modules (see below). I've googled "wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!" and I haven't found a good explanation of how to fix it in this context. Can anyone help me out?

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Aug  1 2011, 15:52:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pkgutil.py:110: DeprecationWarning: twisted.flow is unmaintained.
  __import__(name)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/twisted/words/im/__init__.py:8: UserWarning: twisted.im will be undergoing a rewrite at some point in the future.
  warnings.warn("twisted.im will be undergoing a rewrite at some point in the future.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.py", line 348, in __call__
    return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py", line 1645, in __call__
    self.help(request)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py", line 1682, in help
    elif request == 'modules': self.listmodules()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py", line 1803, in listmodules
    ModuleScanner().run(callback)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pydoc.py", line 1854, in run
    for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages():
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pkgutil.py", line 110, in walk_packages
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/tmp/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-13~231/2.5/DSTROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/wxaddons/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "/var/tmp/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-13~231/2.5/DSTROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_misc.py", line 3298, in __init__
wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

Comment: I actually know the error / exception, but there is no reason why `help("modules")` should throw one.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029053/helpmodules-crashing-not-sure-how-to-fix .

Comment: Bug. Report it to them. They should never be running code like this at import time.

Answer (score 0):

if you call `help('modules')` then, as defined in your `site.py`, `pydoc.help()` is called.

This results in a call to Helper.listmodules() which then calls the `ModuleScanner()` which is 'An interruptible scanner that searches module synopses' as per its docstring.

Unfortunately not all modules/packages are capable of being scanned, as that includes importing the module. You are however lucky that you just get an error. On my system (Linux, Python 2.7.3) this gives a segmentation fault